# Flux of a vector field over a sphere

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

I have been given $\bar{F}=x\hat{x}+xy\hat{y}+xyz\hat{z}$, and I need to compute the flux over a sphere of radius $2$ which I assume is centered at the origin. I have already computed this using the divergence theorem. I begin with $$\int_S\bar{F}\cdot \bar{da}$$

where $$\bar{F}\cdot\bar{da}=(x\hat{x}+xy\hat{y}+xyz\hat{z})\cdot\frac{x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\vert da\vert$$

where the magnitude is $\vert da \vert=r^2\sin^2\theta d\theta d\phi$. So I'm immediately stuck in this problem, because the dot product term is tricky. I've tried to simplify it via factoring terms etc, but no luck so far. Eventually this will be computed in spherical coordinates with $r=2$. How should I work with this dot product term?

EDIT : I'm trying to compute the flux, and I am not applying the divergence theorem here.

Comment: If you are applying divergence theorem then you need to find  divergence of the vector field first and it is a volume integral

Comment: I can't see $\;\text{div}\, f\;$ that you say you used...You should get $\;\text{div}\, f=1+x+xy\;$, and if you want to use then polar coordinates then you get $\;1+r\cos\theta\left(1+\sin\theta\right)\;$ ....and don't forget the Jacobian.

Comment: @variations I have edited my answer and I have shown how to integrate using both divergence theorem and direct surface integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divergence Theorem gives:-

$$\iint_{S}F\,dS=\iiint_{V}\nabla\cdot F\,dV$$

$$\nabla\cdot F = 1+x+xy$$.

Now you convert into spherical polar coordinates and integrate over the sphere

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(1+r\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)+r^{2}\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)\sin^{2}(\theta)\right)r^{2}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\,dr$$.

The integral is actually much simpler as $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\phi)\,d\phi=0$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)\,d\phi=0$

So only the first term survives and gives you $\frac{4\pi}{3}\cdot 2^{3}$ which is precisely the volume of the sphere.

Else you can also view it logically. both $x$ and $xy$ are symmetric about the sphere. So their volume integral should give you $0$. So only the term for $1$ survives. And integral of $1$ over the volume of the sphere is precisely the volume of the sphere.

Otherwise if you want to go for direct surface integral as you were trying , you need to integrate over the surface of the upper hemisphere with the normal vector oriented towards the positive $z$ axis. And for the lower hemisphere you need the normal oriented towards negative $z$ axis and then integrate using $\iint_{S}F\,dS=\iint \frac{F\cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{n}\cdot \hat{z}|}\,dxdy$ for both the upper and lower hemisphere.

the normal vector to the surface of the sphere is given by the gradient

So we have for the upper hemisphere where $z=\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}$

So the gradient would be $\hat{z}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\hat{x}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\hat{y}$

Following the formula I gave above we get:-

The integral is :-

$$\iint_{D}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}+\frac{xy^{2}}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}+xyz\right)\,dxdy$$.

Convert to polar coordinates to get

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(r^{2}\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}+r^{3}\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)+r^{2}\left(4-r^{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-r^{2}}}rdtdr$$.

Similarly we do it for the lower hemisphere. The only difference is that
for the normal you would need to find the gradient of $z=-\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}$ . And as you might have guessed , we need to keep it pointed towards $-\hat{z}$ .

So we actually need to find the gradient of $ -\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}-z\equiv 0$

We get the gradient as $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\hat{x}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\hat{y}-\hat{z}$$

Now again following the formula and converting to polar we get

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(r^{2}\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}+r^{3}\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)-r^{2}\left(4-r^{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-r^{2}}}rdtdr$$

Add them up to get

$$2\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(r^{2}\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}+r^{3}\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-r^{2}}}rdtdr$$

Now again $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(t)\cos(t)\,dt=0$

So we have :-

$$2\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{r^{2}\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}}{\sqrt{4-r^{2}}}rdtdr$$

$$=2\pi\int_{0}^{2}\frac{r^{3}}{\sqrt{4-r^{2}}}\,dr=\frac{32\pi}{3}$$

Thus both ways give the same answer.

Remember that you cannot integrate over the whole sphere at once. You have to respect the direction of the normal and break it into upper and lower hemisphere.

Comment: But certainly the direction of the normal vector is normal to the surface everywhere? That means the area element $dS$ is always directed along the radial unit vector?

Comment: Normal to the surface means two directions, one pointing inward and another pointing outward of a closed surface. For calculating the flux, you need to take the outward pointing vector. Remember Gauss Law of Physics? It is exactly like that .

Comment: @variations Just try and vizulaize what is happening, if for the lower hemisphere the normal vector was pointing "upwards" then it would point inward to the surface and go inside the sphere. So you need to make it such that the $\hat{z}$ component is negative. So that it points downwards. And also you cannot integrate directly over the sphere, the integration is not even defined near the equator. That is because the cartesian system is not spherically symmetric. Yes if  you manage to find the normal vectors in spherical coordinates, then you can integrate over the whole sphere at once.